# How to popup modal only when the Ajax function finish execution in bootstrap jquery?

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `Ajax` function like this:

```
function generate_summary() {
    var summary_input=document.getElementById('summary_input').value;
    var email_notify=document.getElementById('email_notify').value;
    var num_sent=document.getElementById('num_sent').value;
      $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/summary/",
                data: {summary_input:summary_input, email_notify:email_notify, num_sent:num_sent},
                success: function(data){
                     $('#modal-body').html(data)
                }
            });

}
```

I have `href` like this:

```
<a onclick="generate_summary()"  href="#summaryModal" style="text-decoration:none;" id="summarize_btn" role="button" class="btn btn-success offset3" data-toggle="modal">Summarize</a>
```

Modal looks like this:

```
<!-- Summary output popup  -->
<div id="summaryModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Summary</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
    <textarea disabled id="summary_output" name="summary_input" rows="15" class="span5"></textarea> 
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Modal is a popup when summarize button is clicked.

The output from the server is placed on:

```
  <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
    <textarea disabled id="summary_output" name="summary_input" rows="15" class="span5">{{ summary }}</textarea> 
  </div>
```

`Ajax function, modal` everything is working fine. But the modal is load so quickly and the function only returns the value after `10-15 secs`. I want to show the popup modal and the summary at the same time. How can I do that?

Comment: What modal?  I see no modal here, or any instantiate of such.

Comment: load the modal after the ajax call is complete. you can use jQuery dialog.

Answer (score 0):

to use jquery dialog you will have to reference jquery.ui js and css files in your project.

first make the summaryModal a jquery dialog:

```
$("#summaryModal").dialog({ autoOpen: false, buttons:
        {
            "Save": function () {
                if (!confirm("Do you want to save the changes?")) {
                    return;
                }
                //Add your logic to save.

                $("#summaryModal").dialog('close');
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $("#summaryModal").dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```

After that when you click the summarize_btn make the ajax call and load the content in the dialog:

```
$("#summarize_btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/About",
            success: function (data) {

                $("#summaryModal").dialog("option", "height", 500);
                $("#summaryModal").dialog("option", "width", 500);
                $("#summaryModal").dialog("option", "title", 'Modal Title');
                $("#summaryModal").dialog("option", "modal", true);
                $("#summaryModal").dialog('open');

                $('#summaryModal').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

the summaryModal div will look like:

```
<div id="summaryModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

</div>
```